# Getting Display Name for UserID twice in same query

Tags: mysql

I have a table called Users:

```
UserID  |  DisplayName
----------------------
2       |  Jack 
3       |  Jill
```

And a table called Tasks:

```
TaskID  |  UserID  |  UserForID
--------------------------------
1       |  2       |  3
2       |  3       |  2
3       |  3       |  3
```

Basically in here, users can set tasks for each other or themselves.

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM Tasks
INNER JOIN Users
ON Tasks.UserForID=Users.UserID
```

Now using `$row['DisplayName']` gets the display name of the user the task is for, but how do I go about getting the display name of the user who posted the task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the same user table for both the users. When you joined for first time you joined based on **UserForID** thats why you were getting only for ForUser, now if you join

```
SELECT t.TaskID, u.DisplayName as ForUser, tu.DisplayName as FromUser
FROM Tasks t
INNER JOIN Users u ON t.UserForID=u.UserID
INNER JOIN Users tu ON tu.UserID=t.UserID
```

The key FromUser will contain the name of the user who created the task

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, thanks but this is throwing `There was an error running the query [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM Tasks as t INNER JOIN Users u ON t.UserForID=u.UserID INNER JOIN Users t' at line 2]`

Comment: @BN83 Sorry my bad, there was **,** at the end of **select**. Please check now

Comment: Thanks, that grabs results, however `$TaskFor = $row['ForUser'];$TaskBy = $row['FromUser'];` Are showing the same Display Name even though they should be different.

Comment: @BN83 Its because one of your result is having 3 | 3 for both the users. I think thats why it might be showing that way

Comment: The task i'm looking at has UserID 2 ForUserID 3 but User 3's Display Name is showing for both. Could it be `u.DisplayName as ForUser` that is the reason for this?

Comment: Ya i think so. Here with adding the image for the query that I ran in my localhost. Which helps you to visualize it for better

Comment: Ok, so looking at that image, I have instances where Jack will set an event for Jill, however the name for both "Task For" and "Task By" show up as Jill.

Comment: @BN83 Totally my bad.  Changed the query and screen shot. Please check now.